# Sending Devise emails through Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, resque

I'm trying to send Devise emails through Resque.

Regular emails are getting sent through Resque just fine. And Devise emails are sent just fine, but not Devise emails through Resque. I get "Could not find a valid mapping" which implies that my helper overrides aren't getting picked up.

I'm following this http://shaker.4-dogs.biz/2011/08/06/using-resque-to-send-mail-for-devise/

The odd thing is that to debug it I'm using a local copy of Devise and adding breakpoints in 'initialize_from_record' in Devise, which gets hit when I just use Devise alone. But when I send the Devise emails through resque the breakpoints don't get hit:

```
class ResqueMailer < Devise::Mailer
  include Resque::Mailer
end

config.mailer = "ResqueMailer"
```

And resque instead shows a packaged gem path and not my local source such as:

```
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@evergreen/gems/devise-1.4.9/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb:20:in `devise_mail'
```

Any idea why it's not using my local gem source AND/OR how to get Resque to send my Devise emails?

Comment: This appears to be fixed with the latest version of resque_mailer (2.2.3).

Answer (score 8):

An easy way is to use the [devise-async](https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async) gem.

Add the gem to your Gemfile

```
# Gemfile
gem "devise-async"
```

Configure Devise to use the proxy mailer.

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.mailer = "Devise::Async::Proxy"
```

[Optional] And finally tell DeviseAsync to use Resque to enqueue the emails.

```
# config/initializers/devise_async.rb
Devise::Async.backend = :resque
```

The gem also supports Sidekiq and Delayed::Job.

Comment: Does this gem go through resque mailer or is it a completely different queue?

Answer (score 4):

*Update: you do not need to do this with `resque_mailer` >= 2.2.3*

The monkey patch at https://github.com/devton/resqued_devise_mailer did not work since it sends the full model as an argument to Resque, which will end up marshaling the object and is frowned upon (see Persistence on https://github.com/defunkt/resque).

Here's what worked for me:

Use the resque_mailer gem: https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer

```
gem 'resque_mailer'
```

Add lib/devise_resque_mailer.rb: see https://gist.github.com/1375726

That creates a new DeviseResqueMailer class that will not change any existing behavior in Resque::Mailer, so you can use that module in other mailers.

config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  require 'devise_resque_mailer'
  config.mailer = "DeviseResqueMailer"
```

Move your devise views from app/views/devise/mailer/ to app/views/devise_resque_mailer/

Comment: The hack above is unnecessary with the latest version of resque_mailer (2.2.3).

Comment: what is the "hack" above? The entire answer or a specific part of the answer?

Comment: The entire answer is the hack. resque_mailer should work out of the box as of 2.2.3+.

Comment: It should just work with Devise out of the box? Does that mean the `devise-async` gem is unneeded? Because that hasn't been my findings.

Comment: You either need `devise-async` or `resque_mailer` to do async mails in devise. If you use `resque_mailer`, you can ignore my answer. *This* answer is a hack that's not needed to get `resque_mailer` to work.

Comment: I just tried this is out and Devise does not send through `resque_mailer` by default if the gem is installed. Is there some additional configuration step? You may want edit your question to reflect the current state of things.

Comment: I am getting error "wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)" using this patch

Comment: self.send( action, record).message.deliver
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)

Comment: I got it working with latest versions of devise and resque-mailer. But had to tweek a little bit. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33114854/762837