# Resque and Resque_mailer with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, resque

I am implementing background email processing with Resque using the resque_mailer gem (https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer). I was able to get it to work for all my emails except the ones sent by Devise.

I went through a bunch of SO questions, and blog posts (for instance http://teeparham.posterous.com/send-devise-emails-with-resque) but could not find a way to get it to work.

What are the precise steps to follow to get resque_mailer to work with Devise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending Devise emails through Resque](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125603/sending-devise-emails-through-resque)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a look at devise-async. Looks like it fits your use case. [Devise Async](https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async)

Comment: Just curious: under what circumstances would I use a custom mailer class (Devise::Async.mailer = "MyCustomMailer")?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would think you would create a custom mailer if you needed to override one of the existing mailer actions, confirmation_instructions, reset_password_instructions, or unlock_instructions, to include more data in the email view.

Answer (score 1):

I went through [tee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125603/sending-devise-emails-through-resque#comment22592328_8172195) and several resources online, but couldn't find a working solution.

After a few days of reading through resque-mailer and devise code, a solution that worked for me. Thanks to tee for [gist](https://gist.github.com/teeparham/1375726) which put me in right direction.

Assuming your `app/mailers/application_mailer.rb` looks similar to

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Resque::Mailer # This will add a `self.perform` class method, which we will overwrite in DeviseResqueMailer
end
```

In `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
Devise.parent_mailer = "ApplicationMailer" 

Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer = 'DeviseResqueMailer'
end
```

In the resource class which uses devise, overwrite the `send_devise_notification` method to send resource class and id instead of object to prevent marshalling

```
# app/models/user.rb
protected    
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  # Based on https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer/blob/64d2be9687e320de4295c1bd1b645f42bd547743/lib/resque_mailer.rb#L81
  # Mailer may completely skip Resque::Mailer in certain cases - and will fail as we write custom handle in DeviseResqueMailer assuming mails are handled via resque
  # So in those cases, don't retain original devise_mailer so things work properly
  if ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries && Resque::Mailer.excluded_environments.exclude?(Rails.env.to_sym)
    # Originally devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver
    # Modified to ensure devise mails are safely sent via resque
    resource_id, resource_class = self.id, self.class.name
    devise_mailer.send(notification, {resource_id: resource_id, resource_class: resource_class}, *args).deliver
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Finally, in `app/mailers/devise_resque_mailer.rb`, fetch the record again from the database and continue

```
class DeviseResqueMailer < Devise::Mailer

  def self.perform(action, *args)
    # Hack to prevent RuntimeError - Could not find a valid mapping for admin.attributes
    record_hash = args.shift
    record = record_hash["resource_class"].constantize.find(record_hash["resource_id"])
    args.unshift(record)
    super # From resque-mailer
  end
end
```

I feel this approach is a better than using devise-async as all the mails go through same code path. Its easier to control and overwrite if needed.

Comment: does this solution still work for you or have you had to make any tweaks? I ask cause I've been fighting with this for a few days. I feel like this solution gets me the closest with devise, resque, and resque_mailer but it is still causing issues. Curious if you had tried the resque_mailer activerecordserializer?

Comment: Our current codebase is still largely the same and are sending devise mails via resque_mailer. What is the error/issue you face? I have modified (updated above) our send_devise_notification method to respect global configuration, but existing code in the answer should be working. 
Tested with devise 3.5.6 & resque_mailer 2.2.7